# got error when use parse connection in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I got this error when I use AWS parse server with my ios app, my app is sometime working fine but got this error another time:

[image]

Why this happened and how can fix it, and what the exact url form I should use?

Comment: Can you share the server logs? also use VERBOSE = 1 on the logs. thanks

Comment: how can get server log ? when i go to log in parse server there is no thing there.

Answer (score 0):

suppously this error happened when i use

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

when i make locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() as comment this error disappear which mean this error happened when the location is updated in my map in app